# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n ((1+\frac{k}{n^2})^{1/3}-1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can I calculate it as follows?

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n ((1+\frac{k}{n^2})^{1/3}-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n(\frac{k}{3n^2}+o(\frac{k}{n^2}))\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{3n^2}+o(\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2})]=\lim_{n\to\infty}[\frac{n(n+1)}{6n^2}+o(\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2})]=1/6\,.$

I think $o(x)+o(y)$ is the higher order infinitesimal of $x+y$ for $x,y>0$, so I write down the second equality. And I'm not sure if the last equality is right.

Comment: you cannot use the notation $y = x + O(x)$ since you cannot ignore the contribution of $O(x)$ to $x$...

Answer (score 3):

Let us note first the inequalities, which hold for $0\le x<1/100$:
$$
1 + \frac 13x -\frac 19x^2 
\le
(1+x)^{1/3}
\le
1 + \frac 13x \ .
$$
To show this, maybe the simplest approach is to go into computations algebraically (instead of taking derivatives and studying monotony of difference functions). We build cubes and obtain equivalently:
$$
1 + x -\frac 5{27}x^3+\frac1{81}x^5-\frac1{729}x^6 
\qquad\le\qquad
1+x
\qquad\le\qquad
1 + x +\frac 13x^2+\frac 1{27}x^3\ ,
$$
and both inequalities are now checked easily.
Now take some $n\ge 100$, so that $k/n^2\le 1/n$ lands in the domain of the shown double inequality. We apply it for $x=k/n^2$ and build the sum, thus getting:
$$
\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\left(
\frac 13\cdot \frac k{n^2}
-
\frac 19\cdot \frac {k^2}{n^4}
\right)
\le
\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\left(
\left(
1+\frac k{n^2}
\right)^{1/3}
-1
\right)
\le 
\sum_{1\le k\le n}
\frac 13\cdot \frac k{n^2}
\ .
$$
Now the needed expression is the sandwich position, and the lower and upper estimation sums are easily computed, as posted. In the limit (for $n\to\infty$), the sum over $k^2/n^4$ does not contribute, since it is
covered by $O(n^3/n^4)$, so the limit comes indeed (on both sides being the same one major and only contribution) from $\bbox[yellow]{\displaystyle \lim_n \sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac 13\cdot\frac k{n^2}=\frac 16}$.

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$ 3\le\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{2/3}+\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{1/3}+1\le
\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{2/3}+\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{1/3}+1\le3+\frac2n$$
and hence
$$ \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac kn}\frac1{3+\frac2n}\le\sum_{k=1}^n \bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{1/3}-1\bigg]=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\frac kn}{\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{2/3}+\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{1/3}+1}\le\frac1{3n}\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac kn}. $$
Hence
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\bigg)^{1/3}-1\bigg]=\frac16.$$